# Unable to install .jar file

Tags: java, android, spring, eclipse, maven

While building my app I came across the following error:

```
Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:
```

---

1. org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=10-robolectric-5803371 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=10-robolectric-5803371 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
2) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:10-robolectric-5803371

So I did exactly what I was told.

1. I manually downloaded the file from Maven respository.
2. Located the file in OS(C:)
3. Tried to install it using the Command Promt

And that's where I run into trouble. I have no idea what's wrong but I won't work.

[Here's what it looks like in the cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM2AU.png)

Comment: Access is denied. Try running command in admin prompt.

Comment: Shouldn't the `-Dfile` path be to the artifact you downloaded, not the Maven installation folder, anyway?